# Integration by parts and U substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I've learned both methods but I'm struggling with when to know when to sue each one.

Example, current problem: $(x^3 + x) \sqrt{x}$. U substitution isn't working, and when I try parts method I get a messy second integral.

Comment: What is U substitution? I have never heard of it. (I suspect it's a newfangled name for something I *do* know.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You may also know it as the anti-chain rule, but most people call it the substitution method or u-substitution.

Comment: @user3032755 I wouldn't use either in this case (see mathlove and Paul's hints), but in general substitution is a good method when a half of the integrand is very similar to the derivative of the other half or when you recognize a good trig sub.  Use integration by parts when you've got a product of two different types of functions and use the LIATE rule to figure out which function should be your $u$ vs $dv$.

Comment: @Bye_World Ah, plain old substitution, is that it? Here I thought it was a *special kind* of substitution, or something. Kind of disappointing, but thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$(x^3+x)\sqrt x=x^3\cdot x^{\frac 12}+x\cdot x^{\frac 12} =x^{\frac{7}{2}}+x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
and that $$\int x^a dx=\frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}+C$$
for $a\not=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(x^3+x)\sqrt{x}=(x^3+x)x^{1/2}=x^{7/2}+x^{3/2}$